# python: return element of array when a mask element is True, and return zero when a mask element is False

Tags: python, numpy

Just say I have an numpy array like this:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

and a mask like this:

```
mask = np.array([True, True, True, False, False])
```

I would like to create an equal sized array with the elements from `a` included whenever that same position is `True` in the mask, and then set the values to zero whenever `False` is present in the mask. The end result would be like this:

```
result = np.array([1,2,3,0,0])
```

any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple element multiplication will do this.  `True` == 1 and `False` == 0.

Comment: [element if flag else 0 for element, flag in zip(a, mask)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
result = np.where(mask, a, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply multiply (as mask of `True` and `False` values is cast to `1` and `0` respectively):

```
res = a * mask
```